# Como hago para no tener que dar un intro para que me salga el mensaje por consola?

Tags: java

A pesar de ser un ejercicio de socket es un problema de java no de socket como tal.Tengo un socket cliente servidor por usuario password y una vez meto lo datos para que continúe la ejecución y me diga login correcto debo de dar un intro en la consola como hago para no tener que hacerlo?

Clase servidor

```
    public class JS15 {

    private int currentTot;
    ServerSocket serversocket;
    protected static boolean listening = true;
    Socket client;
    int bytesRead;
    Conexion c = new Conexion();

    public void start() throws IOException {        
        System.out.println("Connection Starting on port:" + c.getPort());
        //make connection to client on port specified
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(c.getPort());
        //accept connection from client
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection from client");
        while (listening) {
            new Hilo(serversocket.accept()).start();
            System.out.println("conectado");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JS15 server = new JS15();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hilo

```
    public class Hilo extends Thread {

    private Socket client;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintWriter output;
    Conexion c = new Conexion();

    public Hilo(Socket socket) {
        super("EchoThread");
        this.client = socket;
    }

    public void logInfo() throws Exception {
        //open buffered reader for reading data from client
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String username = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("SERVER SIDE " + username);
        String password = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("SERVER SIDE " + password);
        //open printwriter for writing data to client
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getLogin().size(); i++) {
            output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
            if (username.equals(c.getLogin().get(i).getUsuario()) && password.equals(c.getLogin().get(i).getClave())) {
                output.println("Login correcto");
            } else if (i == 3) {
                output.println("Login Failed");
                client.close();
            }
        }
        output.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            logInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println("Server: " + inputLine);
                out.println(inputLine);
                if (inputLine.equals("Adiós.")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problemas de comunicacion con el servidor");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Clase conexión

```
     private static List<UsersYClaves> log;
    private int PORT = 9090;
    private String HOSTNAME = "localhost";

    public Conexion() {
        log = new ArrayList();  
        cargarArray();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.PORT;
    }

    public String gethostName() {
        return this.HOSTNAME;
    }

    public List<UsersYClaves> getLogin() {
        return log;
    }

    public void setLogin(List<UsersYClaves> login) {
        this.log = login;
    }

    public static void cargarArray() {
        UsersYClaves a = new UsersYClaves("grego", "grego1234");
        UsersYClaves b = new UsersYClaves("alba", "alba1234");
        UsersYClaves c = new UsersYClaves("pedro", "pedro1234");
        log.add(a);
        log.add(b);
        log.add(c);
    }
}
```

Clase cliente

```
    public class JC15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String FILENAME = null;
        Conexion c = new Conexion();
        Socket socket;
        BufferedReader in;
        PrintWriter out;
        String serverHostname = "127.0.0.1";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            serverHostname = args[0];
        }
        socket = new Socket(c.gethostName(), c.getPort());
        //create printwriter for sending login to server
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
        //send user name to server
        out.println(username);
        //prompt for password
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Password");
        //send password to server        
        out.println(password);
        out.flush();      
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput;
        out.println("Escribe (\"Adiós.\" para cerrar)");
        out.print("Mensaje: ");
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            if (userInput.equals("Adiós.")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(""+ in.readLine());
            System.out.print("Mensaje: ");
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

El problema es en el cliente una vez este el login para que salga esto   `out.println("Escribe (\"Adiós.\" para cerrar)");` debo de dar un intro y para que el servidor me ponga `login` correcto que sale antes de eso también debo de haberle dado y quiero eliminarlo.

Comment: `input.readLine()` requiere leer el caracter de fin de linea para devolverte los datos, por lo tanto estás obligado a enviarlo (si estás en la consola dando Enter).

Comment: pero el readline viene despues del esribe adios para cerrar

Comment: Puedes usar el método `InputStream#read()` que lee byte a byte, pero seguirás teniendo el problema que si trabajas desde la consola no estoy seguro de que esta envie datos sin detectar el Enter.

Comment: ¿En qué momento es lo que comentas entonces?

Comment: out.println("Escribe (\"Adiós.\" para cerrar)"); justo antes de eso hay que dar enter para que salga eso y login valido

Answer (score 2):

`input.readLine()` requiere leer el caracter de fin de linea para devolverte los datos, por lo tanto estás obligado a enviarlo (si estás en la consola dando Enter).

Puedes usar el método `InputStream#read()` que lee byte a byte, pero seguirás teniendo el problema que si trabajas desde la consola no estoy seguro de que esta envie datos sin detectar el Enter.

**Según actualización de la pregunta y comentarios**

Si tu problema está aquí:

```
out.println("Escribe (\"Adiós.\" para cerrar)");
out.print("Mensaje: ");
```

Me parece que te estás aquivocando. Lo que hacen esas líneas es enviar esos mensajes al servidor y si lo que quieres hacer es imprimirlos en la consola del cliente debes usar `System.out`.

```
System.out.println("Escribe (\"Adiós.\" para cerrar)");
System.out.print("Mensaje: ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente:

1. El cliente envía el nombre de usuario y el servidor lo recibe
2. El cliente envía el password y el servidor lo recibe
3. Aquí viene el problema: el server valida el nombre de usuario y contraseña pero el cliente no espera la respuesta, sino espera una entrada desde la consola. Desincronizacion total . El servidor envía e mensaje de `logon correcto` pero el cliente sigue esperando al usuario que ingrese datos, por lo tanto, cuando le das enter recién recibes el resultado del login.

Antes que entres al while debes esperar el resultado del login haciendo un `readline`:

```
String respuesta = in.readLine();
System.out.println(respuesta);
if(respuesta.equaĺs("Login correcto")) {

    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
```

---

**EDICIÓN:** En el hilo del servidor tambien tienes que hacer un ajuste porque cada vez que el servidor recibe algo del cliente lo devuelve dos veces (doble eco).

```java
// Hacer mientras reciba algo del cliente
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

// Se recibió algo del cliente
// Devolver al cliente "Server " + lo recibido

  out.println("Server: " + inputLine);
// Devolver nuevamente lo recibido al cliente
  out.println(inputLine);

  if (inputLine.equals("Adiós.")) {
      break;
  }
```

Me parece que lo que quieres hacer apenas recibas es imprimir en la consola del server:

```java
System.out.println("Server: " + inputLine);
```

Por otro lado, te recomendaría que cuando te refieras a los socketa  utilices  nombres de variables alusivos a éste (clientIn, clientOut, sockIn,sockOut) de manera que no puedas confundir con los `in` y `out` del Sistema.

En el cliente la línea `System.out.print("Mensaje: ")` esta fuera de contexto.

Comment: con eso me envia el login correcto pero me descuadra el eco no rula bien

Comment: "...el eco no rula bien.." ¿cómo es eso? Por si acaso, cambia los ``out.println`` por ``System.out.println`` en los mensajes que quieres vayan a consola, como lo indica @E.Betanzos. Este último es un error accesorio a tu problema del ``enter``

Comment: a ver es un servidor de eco si pongo lo que me habeis dicho el eco no funciona bien va con retraso cts al segundo mensaje con el primero qeu le envie